# Are any parts of Sokol suits re-used?

Tags: reuse, spacesuits, sokol-spacesuit

The Sokol spacesuit is the Russian launch and re-entry suit.  They appear to be custom-made for each cosmonaut, with mission patches and nametags sewn on to the suit.

Even if the suit as a whole is not re-used, **do any parts of the suit get re-used for other missions or other cosmonauts?**  Or is the entire suit retired after a mission?

[image: Sokol suit]

Comment: This is a disposable spacesuit (Made-to-order http://www.gctc.ru/main.php?id=4813). I don't see any benefit in reusing any of its components. The next version (Сокол-М) will be reusable.

Comment: @A. Rumlin - good info! But are any sources available about new Sokol-M and its reusability?

Comment: @Heopps "The new spacesuit can be used for 10 flights, it will be reusable, with the ability to adjust to different parameters of the cosmonaut's body. Today's spacesuits are sewn individually for each cosmonaut." https://ria.ru/20190829/1558027649.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a disposable spacesuit (Made-to-order gctc.ru/main.php?id=4813). I didn't manage to find information about any benefit in reusing any of its components. The next version spacesuit (Сокол-М) will be reusable.

> "The new spacesuit can be used for 10 flights, it will be reusable,
> with the ability to adjust to different parameters of the cosmonaut's
> body. Today's spacesuits are sewn individually for each cosmonaut."

http://ria.ru/20190829/1558027649.html

Comment: Some suits are reused as museum exhibits... I also have a recollection that the suits get reused for training, but haven't been able to source that. (perhaps an interview with Helen Sharman about the suits she trained in)

Comment: @JCRM Yes, this type of spacesuit is often seen as a "gift from an cosmonaut" in various museums. For example https://www.oblgazeta.ru/society/space/99169/